# Getting the ID in a controller the correct way?

Tags: yii

I have a controller called:

```
CarController
```

in it I have a function called:

```
public function actionView
```

This means I can easily call:

```
www.mysite.com/Car/View
```

But I want to eb able to call:

```
www.mysite.com/Car/View/1
```

Where 1 is the ID of the car in the database. If I call it like that and print our the $_REQUEST object, I see:

```
Array ( 
  [1] => 
)
```

What is the correct way, using YII's built-in features, to get the 1. I can hack it by just asking for the key in the array, but that doesn't seem like it's the correct way?

Comment: www.mysite.com/Car/View/1 is a alias of www.mysite.com/Car/1 in the standard rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it one of several ways, but all require you to set up the routing properly.

First if you configure your routes properly, they become parameterized, and you can do cool things like routing to a specific action if an `id` is passed in the URL:

From config/main.php:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
```

This looks for the URL with just an id and passes it directly to the view action in the controller, so no need to type `mysite.com/car/view/1`, you can instead just do `mysite.com/car/1`

You can also set it up like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/coolAction/<myParam:\w+>'=>'<controller>/coolAction',
```

In your action function you can do this:

```
public function actionCoolAction($myParam){
    echo $myParam;
}
```

You can rename the $myParam to whatever you like, but the parameters are passed in order, so if you have multiple parameters:

```
 '<controller:\w+>/coolAction/<myParam:\w+>/<secondParam:\w+>'=>'<controller>/coolAction',
```

The first parameter passed to your action would be `myParam`, and the second would be `secondParam`.

If you look at the actions generated by Gii, you see that the view, update, and delete actions all have the `$id` parameter being used, and it is configured that way in the routing.

Because it is in the URL, the parameters are also `$_GET` variables and can be retrieved that way as well (`$_GET['id']` or `$_GET['myParam']`)

If you want to be technical, you can use Yii's `Yii::app()->request->id` or `Yii::app()->request->myParam` which will do the same thing.

**CAUTION**

If you configure a route to accept parameters such as an id, and an id is not present, it will throw an error.  That is why using `$_GET` or `Yii::app()->request->` can be better.

Take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url for help with routing.